# Autoencoder predictions for extremely simple task does not make intuitive sense

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, keras, autoencoders, cross-entropy

I am training a simple autoencoder in Keras. The input is of length two, where each element can either be 0 or 1. This gives four distinct input possibilities: [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]. Since there is no noise present, the input can only be these four options.

It does not really make sense to use an autoencoder here, but I am trying to build a basic understanding and make sure my general approach works for simple problems with known outcomes before proceeding to more complex problems that involve adding noise, etc.

I realize this is applied to images so may not directly translate, but I used this tutorial as a starting point: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html. Here is the structure I used (I made this up, not a ton of intuition behind this architecture choice but wanted to keep it simple and take into account the input/output data format).

```
input_dim = 2
encoded_dim = 4
input_ = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
encoded_ = Dense(encoded_dim, activation='relu')(input_)
decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='relu')(encoded_) 
output = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(decoded) # because output should be between 0 and 1
autoencoder = Model(input_, output)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy') # because each output node in the autoencoder should be a 0 or 1 corresponding to reconstructed input
autoencoder.fit(inputs, inputs, batch_size = 8, epochs=12, validation_split = 0.20)
```

However, I am finding the loss to be extremely high and that the predicted output does not correspond at all the input. However, I find this extremely surprising because the problem itself is extremely simple and does not require NNs to solve efficiently since there is no noise/variability in the data. In fact, setting most of the weights to 0 and a few to 1 solves the problem. Do you have any thoughts on why this problem might be difficult for a NN to solve or why my specific approach (architecture choice, loss or activation functions) would not work for this problem? I would appreciate any feedback/improvements/suggestions to help learn. Thank you!

Comment: `encoded_dim` is never used in your code... The network you use is hardly an autoencoder as it is missing any "bottleneck" part that would require "encoding" the information... This network could simply pass the data through (if it weren't for the sigmoid output, which can output 0 and 1 only if its inputs approach infinity).

Comment: Apologies, I made fixed `encoded_dim` (my original code uses `encoded_dim` but I made a mistake when copying the code over). Is your point that `encoded_dim > input_dim` so it's not actually encoding anything? I probably have to make `input_dim` larger than 2 for this case, but is your suggestion to make `encoded_dim < input_dim`.